# Gmail push notifications stop when IMPORTANT or CATEGORY_PERSONAL are excluded

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail push notifications to determine when an email has been assigned to a custom label.  It seems that custom labels are not supported by labelIds so I am using 'exclude' to exclude built-in labels.  This works fine for most of the built-in labels but if I include 'IMPORTANT' OR 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL' in labelIds then push notifications stop completely.

For example:

**Push messages are sent:**

```
service.Users.Watch(new WatchRequest()
{
    TopicName = "projects/tutorial-test-1348/topics/my-new-topic",
    LabelFilterAction = "exclude",
    LabelIds = new string[] { "TRASH",  "SPAM", "DRAFT", "SENT", "STARRED", "INBOX", "CHAT", "UNREAD", "CATEGORY_FORUMS", "CATEGORY_SOCIAL", "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS"}
}, "me").Execute();
```

**Push messages are not sent**

```
service.Users.Watch(new WatchRequest()
{
    TopicName = "projects/tutorial-test-1348/topics/my-new-topic",
    LabelFilterAction = "exclude",
    LabelIds = new string[] { "IMPORTANT", "TRASH",  "SPAM", "DRAFT", "SENT", "STARRED", "INBOX", "CHAT", "UNREAD", "CATEGORY_FORUMS", "CATEGORY_SOCIAL", "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS"}
}, "me").Execute();
```

Comment: Are you getting any  errors messages?

Comment: No errors, the messages no longer arrive.  If I re-send the watch request omitting IMPORTANT  or CATEGORY_PERSONAL then messages start arriving again.  Is there somewhere in the Google Cloud console where error messages would be logged?